# getImageData and putImageData for Canvas Puzzle Project

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following code for working with my canvas:

```
function clickBox() //Get every cell by coordinate on the grid.
{
    var xRectFill = 0; //We start our search on the left side of the board.
    var yRectFill = 0; //We start our search at the top of the board.
    var rectFillArrayX = []; //We will store every X-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var rectFillArrayY = []; //We will store every Y-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var mouseX = event.offsetX;
    var mouseY = event.offsetY;
    for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 8; i3++) //We will fill the X and Y values of our storage array here.
    {
        rectFillArrayX[i3] = xRectFill; //We will get each individual X-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        rectFillArrayY[i3] = yRectFill; //We will get each individual Y-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        xRectFill += 72; //After we fill an X value, we will use the value of the next cell.
        yRectFill += 72; //After we fill a Y value, we will use the value of the next cell.
    }
    for (i4 = 0; i4 <= 8; i4++)
    {
        if (mouseX >= rectFillArrayX[i4] && mouseX <= (rectFillArrayX[i4] + 72))
        {
            for (i5 = 0; i5 <= 8; i5++)
            {
                if (mouseY >= rectFillArrayY[i5] && mouseY <= (rectFillArrayY[i5] + 72))
                {
                    ctx.clearRect(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5], 71, 71);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am practicing with canvas by designing a sudoku puzzle. I have a 9 x 9 grid, and the function "clickBox" currently gets the coordinates of the mouse and clears a cell. Everything in this function works as expected when called from a mouse click event.

What I would like to do now, is to make a copy of the portion of the canvas that was cleared by clearRect, and place that copy back into the canvas whenever I click another area.

I have tried several different approaches and tinkered around a bit. I think I need to use the canvas functions getImageData and putImageData, but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

I have tried storing my X and Y coordinates at the moment a box gets cleared, then passing those coordinates to getImageData, then placing the putImageData in whenever a new click occurs. I am not sure whether I was doing it correctly, and get/put never seemed to do anything.

The theory I had was to use getImageData just before the clearRect function happens, then, on the next click, use putImageData on the previously clicked cell.

Can someone show me a proper use of getImageData and putImageData for this project?

This is my attempt to solve:

```
function clickBox() //Get every cell by coordinate on the grid.
{
    var xRectFill = 0; //We start our search on the left side of the board.
    var yRectFill = 0; //We start our search at the top of the board.
    var rectFillArrayX = []; //We will store every X-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var rectFillArrayY = []; //We will store every Y-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var mouseX = event.offsetX;
    var mouseY = event.offsetY;

    if (lastLocation[0] != null)
    {
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, lastLocation[0], lastLocation[1], 70);
    }
    for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 8; i3++) //We will fill the X and Y values of our storage array here.
    {
        rectFillArrayX[i3] = xRectFill; //We will get each individual X-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        rectFillArrayY[i3] = yRectFill; //We will get each individual Y-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        xRectFill += 72; //After we fill an X value, we will use the value of the next cell.
        yRectFill += 72; //After we fill a Y value, we will use the value of the next cell.
    }
    for (i4 = 0; i4 <= 8; i4++)
    {
        if (mouseX >= rectFillArrayX[i4] && mouseX <= (rectFillArrayX[i4] + 72))
        {
            for (i5 = 0; i5 <= 8; i5++)
            {
                if (mouseY >= rectFillArrayY[i5] && mouseY <= (rectFillArrayY[i5] + 72))
                {
                    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i4], 72, 72);
                    var lastLocation = [rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5]];
                    ctx.clearRect(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5], 71, 71);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
function clickBox() //Get every cell by coordinate on the grid.
{
    var xRectFill = 0; //We start our search on the left side of the board.
    var yRectFill = 0; //We start our search at the top of the board.
    var rectFillArrayX = []; //We will store every X-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var rectFillArrayY = []; //We will store every Y-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var mouseX = event.offsetX;
    var mouseY = event.offsetY;
    var lastLocation = [];

    if (typeof lastLocation[0] !== 'undefined')
    {
        alert("Array is defined");
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, lastLocation[0], lastLocation[1], 70);
    }
    for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 8; i3++) //We will fill the X and Y values of our storage array here.
    {
        rectFillArrayX[i3] = xRectFill; //We will get each individual X-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        rectFillArrayY[i3] = yRectFill; //We will get each individual Y-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        xRectFill += 72; //After we fill an X value, we will use the value of the next cell.
        yRectFill += 72; //After we fill a Y value, we will use the value of the next cell.
    }
    for (i4 = 0; i4 <= 8; i4++)
    {
        if (mouseX >= rectFillArrayX[i4] && mouseX <= (rectFillArrayX[i4] + 72))
        {
            for (i5 = 0; i5 <= 8; i5++)
            {
                if (mouseY >= rectFillArrayY[i5] && mouseY <= (rectFillArrayY[i5] + 72))
                {
                    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i4], 72, 72);
                    var lastLocation = [rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5]];
                    ctx.clearRect(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5], 71, 71);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5P19.jpg)

Comment: Please include your attempt to solve the problem above

Comment: Post was edited to include attempt to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed it.

```
function clickBox() //Get every cell by coordinate on the grid.
{
    var xRectFill = 0; //We start our search on the left side of the board.
    var yRectFill = 0; //We start our search at the top of the board.
    var rectFillArrayX = []; //We will store every X-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var rectFillArrayY = []; //We will store every Y-Coordinate of a cell here.
    var mouseX = event.offsetX;
    var mouseY = event.offsetY;
    if (typeof lastLocation !== 'undefined' && lastLocation.length > 0)
    {
        // the array is defined and has at least one element
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, lastLocation[0], lastLocation[1]);
    }
    for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 8; i3++) //We will fill the X and Y values of our storage array here.
    {
        rectFillArrayX[i3] = xRectFill; //We will get each individual X-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        rectFillArrayY[i3] = yRectFill; //We will get each individual Y-Coordinate and store from [0-8]
        xRectFill += 72; //After we fill an X value, we will use the value of the next cell.
        yRectFill += 72; //After we fill a Y value, we will use the value of the next cell.
    }
    for (i4 = 0; i4 <= 8; i4++)
    {
        if (mouseX >= rectFillArrayX[i4] && mouseX <= (rectFillArrayX[i4] + 72))
        {
            for (i5 = 0; i5 <= 8; i5++)
            {
                if (mouseY >= rectFillArrayY[i5] && mouseY <= (rectFillArrayY[i5] + 72))
                {
                    lastLocation = [rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5]];
                    ctx.clearRect(rectFillArrayX[i4], rectFillArrayY[i5], 71, 71);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a global getImageData variable elsewhere, and added a check near the start of the function to see if the array was created, instead of creating an empty array beforehand.

Final additions:

```
if (typeof lastLocation !== 'undefined' && lastLocation.length > 0)
        {
            // the array is defined and has at least one element
            ctx.putImageData(imgData, lastLocation[0], lastLocation[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need to create a table with these portions as table cells. Then you can easily hide and unhide a cell on events or whatever.

You can set `<tr id="your_cell" style="display: none;">` and then show it back with JavaScript:

```
var cell_with_data = document.getElementById('your_cell').style;
cell_with_data.display = 'table-row'/'block';
```

Cells can be removed by

```
var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
row.deleteCell(0);
```

Just a suggestion btw.

Comment: I have done this successfully. The goal was to do it a bit differently with canvas. Thanks for the suggestion, though.